# How to create a multi column dropdown list compatible with Angular 4/5?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material, dropdown, semantic-ui

I am working on an Angular application in which I have to create a multi column dropdown list as shown in the below image.
[image]

Although I was able to develop it with the help of a selectMenu widget of jQuery but later on while using this way, this widget didn't work properly when I was fetching the asynchronous data from store using observables. Although this widget was working properly when I was providing the data through a hard-coded array.

Next, I look for another alternatives. I found Angular Material dropdown component but I don't understand how do I create multi column in that component.

I also find semantic UI dropdown component that was providing the functionality similar to the dropdown widget. But forget creating the dropdown, I am not even able to initiate that dropdown because of some jQuery issue. I have read from many sources that I shouldn't use jQuery with Angular but fact is that I have no solution or alternative currently to create that widget. So, can anyone help me out on how do I create such a multi column dropdown list.

Answer (score 1):

**Bootstrap 4.0**

You are able to you a [Bootstrap flexbox container](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) to create the columns within an ng-bootstrap dropdown. I was able to replicate the desired dropdown list in the code example below.

Note that the width of the element that has the ngbDropdownMenu directive needs to be specified. Also, extra CSS is required to align things nicely :)

It was straightforward to implement the layout in the desired dropdown list using Bootstrap flexbox containers. YMMV for other layouts.

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
  <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1" style="width: 600px;">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div>
        PREFERRED OPTIONS
      </div>
      <div>
        PRICE
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ngbDropdownItem class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div>
        L
      </div>
      <div>
        Standard Screw Adjustment
      </div>
      <div>
        $0.00
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div>
        STANDARD OPTIONS
      </div>
      <div>
        PRICE
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ngbDropdownItem class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div>
        C
      </div>
      <div>
        Tamper Resistant - Factory Set
      </div>
      <div>
        $5.00
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ngbDropdownItem class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div>
        K
      </div>
      <div>
        Handknob
      </div>
      <div>
        $6.00
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div>
        ADDITIONAL OPTIONS
      </div>
      <div>
        PRICE
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ngbDropdownItem class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div>
        F
      </div>
      <div>
        Hex Head Screw with Locknut
      </div>
      <div>
        $-4.00
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ng-bootstrap and customize dropdown component '[ngbDropdown](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples)' :